# Form new array from associative arrays

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I have 3 arrays and looks like this

```
Array1
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [Month] => 'Jan 2015'
        [Total] => 10
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [Month] => 'Feb 2015'
        [Total] => 8
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [Month] => 'Mar 2015'
        [Total] => 10
    )
)

Array2
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [Month] => 'Jan 2016'
        [Total] => 7
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [Month] => 'Feb 2016'
        [Total] => 5
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [Month] => 'Mar 2016'
        [Total] => 15
    )
)

Array3
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [Month] => 'Jan 2017'
        [Total] => 13
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [Month] => 'Feb 2017'
        [Total] => 10
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [Month] => 'Mar 2017'
        [Total] => 11
    )
)
```

All 3 arrays are of the same size.

What I want to achieve is to output identical months sequentially and corresponding values in the same order. The new arrays should look like this:

*Desired result:*

```
$months = array['Jan 2015','Jan 2016','Jan 2017', 'Feb 2015', 'Feb 2016'...'Mar 2016','Mar 2017'];
$totals = array[10,7,13,5,5,...,15,11];
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: I need a hint on how to approach it and then I will write the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this https://eval.in/829000

```
<?php
$array1 = Array
(
    0 => Array ( 'Month' => 'Jan 2015', 'Total' => 10 ),
    1 => Array ( 'Month' => 'Feb 2015', 'Total' => 8),
    2 => Array ( 'Month' => 'Mar 2015', 'Total' => 10)
);

$array2 = Array
(
    0 => Array( 'Month' => 'Jan 2016', 'Total' => 7),
    1 => Array( 'Month' => 'Feb 2016', 'Total' => 5),
    2 => Array( 'Month' => 'Mar 2016', 'Total' => 15)
);

$array3 = Array
(
    0 => Array( 'Month' => 'Jan 2017', 'Total' => 13),
    1 => Array( 'Month' => 'Feb 2017', 'Total' => 10),
    2 => Array( 'Month' => 'Mar 2017', 'Total' => 11)
);

//ordered months names in lower case
$monthsNames = ['jan','feb','mar','abr','may','jun','jul','aug','sept','oct','nov','dec'];
$months = [];
$totals = [];
$orderedMonths = [];
$orderedTotals = [];
$orderedIndexes = [];

foreach($array1 as $array){
    $months[] = $array['Month'];
    $totals[] = $array['Total'];
}
foreach($array2 as $array){
    $months[] = $array['Month'];
    $totals[] = $array['Total'];
}
foreach($array3 as $array){
    $months[] = $array['Month'];
    $totals[] = $array['Total'];
}
//now the $months and $totals has all the values but not ordered, we need to order them
//get the indexes order;
foreach ($monthsNames as $monthName){
    $index = 0; //reset the index for the next month
    foreach ($months as $inputMonth){
        //if the $inputMonth == $monthName then collected it's index
        if (strpos(strtolower($inputMonth), $monthName) !== false ){
            $orderedIndexes[] = $index;
        }
        $index ++;
    }
}
//build the final ordered array
foreach ($orderedIndexes  as $index){
    $orderedMonths[] = $months[$index];
    $orderedTotals[] = $totals[$index];
}
var_dump($orderedMonths);
var_dump($orderedTotals);
exit;
?>
```

this outputs

```
array(9) {
  [0]=>
  string(8) "Jan 2015"
  [1]=>
  string(8) "Jan 2016"
  [2]=>
  string(8) "Jan 2017"
  [3]=>
  string(8) "Feb 2015"
  [4]=>
  string(8) "Feb 2016"
  [5]=>
  string(8) "Feb 2017"
  [6]=>
  string(8) "Mar 2015"
  [7]=>
  string(8) "Mar 2016"
  [8]=>
  string(8) "Mar 2017"
}
array(9) {
  [0]=>
  int(10)
  [1]=>
  int(7)
  [2]=>
  int(13)
  [3]=>
  int(8)
  [4]=>
  int(5)
  [5]=>
  int(10)
  [6]=>
  int(10)
  [7]=>
  int(15)
  [8]=>
  int(11)
}
```

note that the totals in your desired result is not the correct order you want, since Feb 2015 is 8 not 5.

also note that if you trust the months string format you can also make use of the PHP date and time functions.

Comment: Desired result achieved using this code. But if you could run me through what is happening around this point `foreach ($monthsNames as $monthName){
    $index = 0;
    foreach ($months as $inputMonth){
        if (strpos(strtolower($inputMonth), $monthName) !== false ){
            $orderIndexes[] = $index;
        }
        $index ++;
    }
}`

Comment: @ScottMensah as we already know that our  `$monthsNames` are ordered we can loop in it's values and collect the indexes of the `jans` then the indexes of the `febs` then the indexes of the `marches` ,.. ,,..., .. to the indexes of Decembers... after that `$orderedIndexes` hold the indexes of the values inside the `$months and $totals` arrays ordered by the months.. I will also update the answer to add comments to this point

Answer (score 0):

You can use a foreach loop:

```
$months = array();
$totals = array();

foreach($array as $var){
    $months[] = $var['Month'];
    $totals[] = $var['Total'];
}
```

Comment: the output I get looks good. `Array ( [0] => Jan 2015 [1] => Feb 2015 [2] => Mar 2015 )`. The issue is that the second element of `$months[]` is the second array which is `Jan 2016`.